# How can i change the sentence and join them in a blade.php file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am new to PHP and laravel so i wanted to ask a simple question. Suppose i have a few words such as "Hello I Am Nutan" and i have brought it in from my database so can i change that to "hello-i-am-nutan". I am trying to implement this in my URL in my project where i want to make my package name to package URL and according to the URL the proper data to be shown in next page so can some one tell me how to change the "Hello I Am Nutan" to "hello-i-am-nutan" in blade.php file.

**My Controller:**

```
 public function package($package_name){
    // your code goes here
 }
public function packages(){
    $packages = Packages::all();
    $converted = Str::kebab();
    return view('pages.packages',compact('packages'),compact('converted'));
}
```

My blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('style')
    <!-- Owl Carousel -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/packages.css">
@endsection

@section('content')
<section id="wrapper" class="skewed">
  <div class="layer bottom"></div>
  <div class="layer top">
      <div class="content-wrap">
        <div class="content-body">
          <h1>Packages</h1>
          <p class="text-capitalize">Scroll Down to learn more about packages</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Property to Buy Start -->
<section class="packages mt-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="package-heading text-center mb-4">
      <h2 class="font-weight-bold text-capitalize">Tour Packages</h2>
      <p>Check out all of our latest tour packages.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="packages owl-carousel owl-carousel2 row mb-5">
      @foreach ($packages as $package)
      @if ($package->Package_Type == 'Tour')
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="package shadow" >
          <div class="package-image">
            <img src="{{$package->Package_Image}}" alt="Kathmandu - Pokhara Trek">
            <div class="package_hover">
            <a href="{{ route('package.name',['package_name' => $converted]) }}">Read More</a>
              <img src="img/svg/heart.svg" alt="" >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="package-description">
            <div class="package-name">
              <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-capitalize">{{$package->Package_Name}} {{$package->Package_Type}}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="package-short-description">
              <p class="text-justify">{{$package->Package_Short_Description}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="package-detail d-flex justify-content-between font-weight-bold">
              <span><i class="far fa-clock"></i> Duration: {{$package->Package_Duration}}Days</span>
              <span><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> Level:{{$package->Package_Level}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="package-price pt-2">
              <span class="font-weight-bold">Tour Price<br/>${{$package->Package_Price}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
      @endif
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- Property to Buy End -->

<!-- Property to Rent  Start  -->
<section class="packages">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="package-heading text-center mb-4">
      <h2 class="font-weight-bold text-capitalize">Trek Packages</h2>
      <p>Check out all of our latest treaking packages.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-carousel2 row mb-5">
      @foreach ($packages as $package)
      @if ($package->Package_Type == 'Trek')
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="package shadow" >
          <div class="package-image">
            <img src="{{$package->Package_Image}}" alt="Kathmandu - Pokhara Trek">
            <div class="package_hover">
            <a href="{{ route('package.name',['package_name' => $converted]) }}">Read More</a>
              <img src="img/svg/heart.svg" alt="" >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="package-description">
            <div class="package-name">
              <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-capitalize">{{$package->Package_Name}} {{$package->Package_Type}}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="package-short-description">
              <p class="text-justify">{{$package->Package_Short_Description}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="package-detail d-flex justify-content-between font-weight-bold">
              <span><i class="far fa-clock"></i> Duration: {{$package->Package_Duration}}Days</span>
              <span><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> Level:{{$package->Package_Level}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="package-price pt-2">
              <span class="font-weight-bold">Tour Price<br/>${{$package->Package_Price}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
      @endif
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- Property to rent  End  -->
@endsection

@section('script')
{{-- Owl Carousel js --}}
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/packages.js"></script>
@endsection
```

i wnat it in
`<a href="{{url('/package/')}}">Read More</a>`

Okay i have not made my routes for the next page but it will be /package/something

```
Route::prefix('/package')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/{package_name}', 'PackageController@package')->name('package.name');
});
```

But it seems that Package_Name is not database data but just plain text how to bring Package_Name in controller inside kebab.
My Migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePackagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('packages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('Package_Banner_Image');
            $table->string('Package_Image');
            $table->string('Package_Type');
            $table->string('Package_Name')->unique();
            $table->integer('Package_Price');
            $table->integer('Package_Duration');
            $table->string('Package_Level');
            $table->string('Package_Short_Description');
            $table->text('Day_One');
            $table->text('Day_Two')->nullable();
            $table->text('Day_Three')->nullable();
            $table->text('Day_Four')->nullable();
            $table->text('Day_Five')->nullable();
            $table->text('Day_Six')->nullable();
            $table->text('Day_Seven')->nullable();
            $table->text('Day_Eight')->nullable();
            $table->text('Day_Nine')->nullable();
            $table->text('Day_Ten')->nullable();
            $table->text('Day_Eleven')->nullable();
            $table->text('Day_Twelve')->nullable();
            $table->text('Day_Thirteen')->nullable();
            $table->text('Day_Fourteen')->nullable();
            $table->text('Day_Fiveteen')->nullable();
            $table->text('Cost_Includes_One');
            $table->text('Cost_Includes_Two')->nullable();
            $table->text('Cost_Includes_Three')->nullable();
            $table->text('Cost_Includes_Four')->nullable();
            $table->text('Cost_Includes_Five')->nullable();
            $table->text('Cost_Includes_Six')->nullable();
            $table->text('Cost_Includes_Seven')->nullable();
            $table->text('Cost_Includes_Eight')->nullable();
            $table->text('Cost_Includes_Nine')->nullable();
            $table->text('Cost_Includes_Ten')->nullable();
            $table->longText('Package_Location');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('packages');
    }
}
```

Comment: You have done it. Where are you stuck?

Comment: i dont know how to write it in blade.php file in anchor href attribute

Comment: Can you show your blade code and where you want it?

Comment: i have added in the question

Comment: Ok, can you show how the route `package` looks like in route file?

Comment: @vivek_23 i have added them

Comment: But your URL don't seem to have any dynamic text with `{}` syntax. How are you going to receive them in your code?

Comment: @vivek_23 i just wrote that in the question can you check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In blade file

```
<?php  $converted = Illuminate\Support\Str::kebab($package['Package_Name']);?>
                           <a href="{{ route('package-info',['package_name' => $converted]) }}">Read More</a>
```

In route file

```
Route::get('/package-info/{package_name}', 'master\webEventController@package_info')->name('package-info');
```

In controller file

```
public function package_info($package_name) {
    $package_name = str_replace('-', ' ', $package_name);
    $package_info = Packages::where('package_name', $package_name)->first();
    return view('')->with('package_info', $package_info);
}
```

Use laravel helper Str::kebab()
See all Helper function here in docs,
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-kebab-case

Comment: @NutanPanta Consider marking this answer as correct.

Comment: But it is not pointing to my migration 'Package Name' is just plain text.

Answer (score 3):

The "hello-i-am-nutan" is called **kebab case**
You can use laravel helper Str::kebab() as in the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-kebab-case

Comment: But can i use it in blade.php file?

Comment: you can pass any value you want from the controller to the view, so yes :)

Comment: can someone show me how to write it in blade.php file in href="{{url('/package')}}"    i whave added my controller at the top.