# How to pass value from route to controller using Laravel 7.0?

Tags: laravel

I have a problem in passing a value from Blade having

`{{ route('<route-name>', '['foe'=> $bar]') }}`

route URL parameter has variable **foe** to Controller

The controller needs a value from this route.

How can I get data of **foe**?

Comment: `{{ route('<route name>', ['foe' => $bar]) }}`

Comment: Ah Ok. Thank you STA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63277934/how-can-i-change-the-sentence-and-join-them-in-a-blade-php-file/63278533#63278533 show on this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route in your web.php should be defined like this:

`Route::get('route-name/{foe}', 'SomeController@show')->name('route-name');`

And in your controller:

```
public function ($foe) {}
```

Now `$foe` should contain the value of variable `$bar`

More on this can be found in the Laravel docs: [Laravel routing, parameters.](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: This is correct, sorry it took me so long to reply and give thanks.
It's been 2 years, thanks @frogeyedman.

Answer (score 2):

It would be :

```
{{ route('<route name>', ['foe' => $bar]) }}
```

Or,

```
{{ route('<route name>', $bar) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `route()` helper function will let you pass parameters to the URL in two different ways:

1. If the route defined has a named parameter, it will be replaced with the parameter name and passed as an argument to the controller:

```php
Route::get('/example/{foe}', Controller::class)->name('example');

route('example', ['foe' => 'bar']); // "/example/bar"

class ExampleController
{
    public function __invoke($foe)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

2. If the route does not have a named parameter, the values provided to the `route()` helper function will be appended as a query string to the final URL, which you can then access from the request object

```php
Route::get('/example', Controller::class)->name('example');

route('example', ['foe' => 'bar']); // "/example?foe=bar"

class ExampleController
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        request('foe');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given on my question, I would like to commend STA and Ankita Patel for solving my problem

The solution is in this syntax:

{{ route('route-name', ['foe' => $bar]) }}